# How do you design for low fidelity displays?

Tags: color, color-reproduction

I own two displays, one is my phone's and one my laptops. I am a programmer, looking to develop for Android. When designing my apps and their logos, I find there there are huge discrepancies in the ways that color displays on my two devices.

When one develops logos and branding for an app or company, how do they account for low color fidelity? My favorite shade of purple, #AA00FF, doesn't display the same on my two devices. How can I design a user experience that looks close enough on varying quality displays?

Comment: Buy every person in the world the same exact display and hope for the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No two display devices display the same color. Even two of the same panels do not display same color as they have small differences in usage history. Also because surrounding conditions affect color perception its not possible to be exact, without specialized tools and processes. The more pedantic or accurate you are the more true this statement is.

In practice you have no control over this, as you can not dominate everybody's settings. The best you can hope is that users regularly calibrate their monitor and that your color profile conversion works as intended. That does not happen often tough. Even profiles do not guarantee same color. But as close or relatively same color. Depending on matching intent settings of your color engine.

As such `#AA00FF` does not specify a color it specifies intensities for the monitor. Since each monitor is different you get this problem. It it only when paired with a color profile data that that becomes a real color definition. Now systems that know what their profile is can try to match the color.

Good read on subject, its long but thorough:

http://people.rit.edu/med2823/colormanageproject/introcolor.html

**TL;DR** Not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You only really need to worry that **a)** The color you use is 'in the ballpark' of the official print colors the brand dictates and **b)** the colors you use look and work together *in relation to each other*.

In other words, how the colors look in relation from one display to the next really isn't nearly as important as few people will be looking at your UI on two different screens at the same time.

UPDATE

Joojaa also brought up a good point. There's another angle to this and that's we simply *can't* enforce consistency across screens. With print, we have complete control over color consistency. We aren't given that same luxury with screens (at least, not yet...)

Comment: Yes this is a good point. It is important for printed materials as papers are often collated next to each other. Possibly from multiple different print runs. Imagine coca cola bottles form 2 different batches in they shop having this kind of discrepancy. **However** this will become a widespread issue on screen. As people will have more screens around, multi monitor setups, tablet next to monitor etc. So it is starting to become critical even digitally. So people are increasingly becoming aware of this.

Comment: @joojaa I mostly agree, though would say brand consistency (including color) Is *always* important. It's just that it's only been doable at this time in print where you can control the medium. We can't control the medium of 'the screen' with any consistency (though to be fair, we've made some progress what with technology improvements such as PNG files supporting color profiles)

Comment: Actually, now that I said that, I realize that should be in the answer. Let me update!